# How to translate a resized canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

Let's say I'm drawing an image to a Javascript canvas. Also, that image will be resized during the drawing operation such that it is horizontally squished. Here's some code that does that:

```js
let dragger = document.querySelector(".dragger");

let canvas = document.querySelector(".my-canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  
let newWidth = 600;
  
image.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  
  dragger.style.left = 0;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, newWidth, canvas.height);
}
  
image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/djqSKFW/sample.jpg";
```

```css
.dragger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragger">
  <canvas class="my-canvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
</div>
```

This all works fine and as expected. However, now let's say you wanted to then translate the image, such that the first 200 pixels are cropped. How would one do this?

It is easy if the image is not being resized, as you just set the 2nd paramter in `drawImage` to `200` and then also execute `dragger.style.left = 200;` (so that both images line up), but once you introduce the additional constraint that the image must maintain its squished width, it seems to become more difficult.

Please note that I am looking to draw this onto the canvas, and not simply have an outer div crop it with `overflow: hidden`. Specifically, I'm looking for a way to draw a properly cropped version of a stretched image.

Edit: As an example to demonstrate the currently undesired behavior, I've made a fiddle that shows how the cropping is not working here: https://jsfiddle.net/604ykmt8/ If you look, you'll notice that how the birds in both images don't line up, even though they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to scale the destination X offset according to the scale factor; see below, adapted from your JSFiddle to draw both images on the same canvas to make things clearer to compare.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector(".my-canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

let newWidth = 600;

function tick () {
  canvas.width = newWidth;
  canvas.height = image.height;
  const offset = 200 + Math.sin(+new Date() / 1000) * 200;
  const ratio = newWidth / image.width;
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, newWidth, canvas.height);
  ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8;
  ctx.drawImage(image, offset, 0, image.width, canvas.height, offset * ratio, 100, newWidth, canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/NNJPfG2/sample.jpg";
image.onload = tick;
```

```html
<canvas class="my-canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to keep the arbitrary width of your image drawn onto the first canvas, when drawing on the second. Instead of making the ImageElement the source for both canvases, just use it for the distortion on the first canvas and actually use this
distorted canvas as the source for your second canvas.

Here's an example:

```js
let otherDragger = document.querySelector(".other-dragger");

let canvas = document.querySelector(".my-canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let otherCanvas = document.querySelector(".my-other-canvas");
let otherCtx = otherCanvas.getContext("2d");

var image = new Image();
image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

let newWidth = 600;

image.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = newWidth;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  otherCanvas.width = newWidth;
  otherCanvas.height = image.height;

  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 1037, canvas.height, 0, 0, newWidth, canvas.height);

  otherDragger.style.left = 100;
  otherCtx.drawImage(canvas, 100, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0, 0, newWidth, canvas.height);
}

image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/NNJPfG2/sample.jpg";
```

```css
.dragger,
.other-dragger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.other-dragger {
  top: 515px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragger">
  <canvas class="my-canvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="other-dragger">
  <canvas class="my-other-canvas" width="1200" height="1200"></canvas>
</div>
```